# Include jQuery script at footer only on mobile and resize friendly

Tags: jquery, media-queries, matchmedia

I'm trying to incorporate a [jQuery plugin by Codrops](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/index5.html) -  that make turns the menu into a bar on the left and bottom. I'd like to use the same menu as a normally top bar on desktop screens, just changing the styles of the id and classes that come with the demo. I was wondering whats the best Javascript solution to include the plugin's scripts on max-width of 768 and then remove them on anything larger. I'd like it to self check and update on browser resize too. Here's what I have so far...

```
 <script>
  (function() {
if( window.innerWidth > 600 ) {
   $.getSscript("assets/js/modernizr.custom.js");
   $.getSscript("assets/js/classie.js");
   $.getSscript("assets/js/borderMenu.js");
}
 })();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some research and I think I found an alternative answer. It doesn't link the scripts, but you can copy and paste them in the function thats called on the mobile screens.

Below is the code I incorporated at the bottom of my footer. I linked all the necessary scripts above this code so it loaded on all screen sizes( the plugin came with a custom modernizer.js and used classie.js)

```
    /////////////////////////////////
    // MATCH MEDIA FOR MOBILE MENU //
    /////////////////////////////////  

   /* JavaScript Media Queries */
if (matchMedia) {
    //*change this to whatever size screens you'd like, I wanted mine to only work on 768 or below
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

   //* Put jQuery plugin's code here


}
```

So far it's worked great. Let me know if you notice anything that could be changed on the above code.

Thanks to [Craig Buckler of OptimalWorks.net](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/) for his great tutorial and the example code.

Comment: The only other issue I'm having is that when I resize the screen the jQuery doesn't execute sometimes. If you know a solution please do share